# How to refresh a webViewController when user wants to refresh it not automatically when navigating from one tab to other

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a webViewController on two tabs, as i navigate from one to the other it will always refresh.

Is there a way to not let the webView Refresh when navigating to it again until the user wants it refreshed?

Comment: please display your code

Comment: in your tabController --> ViewController(Tab 1 and Tab 2) where are you loading url In webView ? ViewWillAppear I think, this is why switching Tabs causing WebView to reload Page again when tabs switched, try loading URL in viewDidLoad , So it won't reload until user itself want to reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you called LoadRequest function in the viewWillAppear? If yes, please try to call that function in viewDidLoad. And call that again when user tap on the refresh button. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it did help !

Comment: awesome @VanoshanRamdhani.. Cheers!